# ERROR: cube viewer is not available!

Tags: software-installation, performance, mpi

I have installed and configured the following:

```
cube-4.2.1
opari2-1.1.1
papi-5.2.0
scalasca-2.0
scorep-1.2.1
```

I am trying to run `scalasca -examine`, but I get the following error:

```
ERROR: cube viewer is not available!
```

Can you instruct me how to fix it?

I ran the installation with the same configuration on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and Kali 1.5 and got the same error on both the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By contacting the support it seems that my CUBE install didn't build the GUI part of CUBE.

The fix was to install libqt4-dev and then reinstall.